# more power for OTG port with external VCC

Tags: ubuntu, usb, omap, usb-otg

I'using a Pandaboard ES with Ubuntu 10.10 server and the ubuntu-omap4-extras Kernel (3.0.0-1205-omap4) and I would like to make use of the second USB-Bus on the Board. The OTG port would provide this second Bus but has unfortunately not enough power to operate for example a webcam.
Therefore I want to use the OTG port as host and provide the Power from the J6 extension (Ground 5VDC and Ground). With $lsusb the device gets recognized but will not work which is probably cause to an internal powercheck.

I found a post in a Gumstick forum to bypass this check:
 "After plugging in the device, run the following command: 
echo -n 1 > /sys/devices/platform/musb_hdrc/usb1/1-1/bConfigurationValue 
This disables the power limit enforcing. You may still get a warning 
in the system log, but the device should work. 
This has to be repeated every time the Overo is rebooted or the device 
is plugged in"

but the suggested path doesn't exist on my pandaboard. Would be great if someone could give me a hint where to turn of the powercheck.
Any help would be appreciated